# executor service in java for multi threading, ignore the details of threading?

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried learning threads and runnable in java and a collegue of mine told me to stop it will take too learn these details. Just lookup how to write an executor. How does this work in java. Can someone provide an example?

Thank you!

Comment: Its always better to know what you are abstracting.

Comment: An executor will not stop you from getting concurrency issues if you're not knowing what you're doing.

Comment: learning threads and runnable will surely help you in understanding underlying concepts for executor as well

Comment: can you provide a simple example of the executor framework that i can use as a foundation for understanding or possibly a template for usability?

Comment: Have you tried to google for executor? If you have any questions after that I am sure the forum would be able to help you out.

Comment: Please give us more details of the program that you want to split up in parallel tasks. Maybe something else is better than making it parallel. Profiling and identifying code which can be optimized might lead to much better results than going through the hurdle of making the whole program be executed in parallel parts. E.g. replacing a ArrayList by a HashSet for lookup can speed up execution in certain situations by factors of 1000 and more (3 seconds instead of an hour). The best thing is that such a change is not complex and therefor the probability for other problems to show up is very low.

Answer (score 0):

To solve small, isolated problems in programming without a bigger project behind, you can go and learn about executors directly. Here is an example of how to use [Threads pools with the Executor Framework](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools), which is suitable as an entry point.

However, if you plan to work more in an environment where concurrency is an important topic, then it is crucial to have a profound understanding of the basics behind more high level concepts. With a good understanding of what happens behind the scenes, you will be able to judge quickly what the best solution is for a problem in regard to performance and scalability.
Without this understanding, the code you write will do what you want it to do, but if it gets applied to slightly different scenarios that you didn't test, it is likely that your code will perform poorly, maybe even be unusable because of performance degredation. Concurrency is a complex topic and the concepts for solutions can't be applied well without good understanding of the matter.

Having said this, I strongly recommend also learning about Threads and Runnable.

Comment: In my current organization, its all about releasing new versions of the software and the business folks run the show. So I have a batch application that takes 8 hrs and the SLA they want is for 4 hrs. Its single threaded. Could you give me a simple example of how the executor framework could be used?

Comment: @TazMan, I understand your situation very well. I've added a link to an example, which will give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: SO the execute() method will be my main guy that will multithread the unit of work?

Comment: If you use Runnable, yes. You might want to use Callables, because they represent long-running computations with results (Runnables have no built-in result mechanism). Callables are explained in the directly next section "Futures and Callables" on the same page. With Callebles, you use the same kind of executor as with Runnables, but instead of execute(), you use submit() to submit a Callable to the executor.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy to understand implementation of an executor that will run three classes together at max:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
Callable<Void> thread1 = new MyClass(); 
executorService.submit(thread1);
Callable<Void> thread2 = new MyClass2(); 
executorService.submit(thread2);                
executorService.shutdown();
```

and the class:

```
public class MyClass implements Callable<Void> {
@Override
public Void call() throws Exception{ }
}
```

It is true you don't need in depth knowledge for basic stuff just keep in mind that if your classes are accessing shared resources with the possibility of conflicts then you need to have a proper thread implementation with locking etc.